# What happens in linux when opening a file?

Tags: linux, file, caching

When using the open() function in linux in order to open a file, is it true that the OS brings all the file blocks to the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the kernel won't systematically on [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) bring all file blocks into its page cache (in particular, that cannot work for files bigger than available RAM).

But it may bring some of them. I guess that for most (small) files, perhaps all blocks could be read. But I could be wrong, and it is highly system specific (and configuration specific too).

See also `O_DIRECT` flag to [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)  & [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) and options for [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html)